# Increment a value if string contains common text, otherwise reset to 1 and continue

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in an Excel file. Everything is the same except the SKU at the end. The SKU either repeats (e.g. HGAF147, HGAF147 S.jpg, etc.) and then goes to another SKU.

Desired result:
[image]

I need to iterate the counter if the SKU is the same, otherwise go back to 1 and reset the counting.

I tried `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2))&"*")`

It continues to count up, despite the SKU changing.
[image]

Comment: You are looking for the substring  on the `LEFT` of the "/", the SKU numbers are, I assume to the `RIGHT`

Comment: Yes that's correct. It still doesn't work, only shows 0?

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,"*" & RIGHT(A2, FIND("/",A2)))`

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work entirely, for example the first 3 skus it shows 1, 1, 1, instead of 1, 2, 3 since there are 3 duplicates (HGAF147)

Comment: I guess you need to be more precise in defining how to identify the SKU? Let's take your example with the 150: Is `150` the SKU? Or `HGAF150`? If the entry has a suffix, is it always separated by a space? Is the number always 3 digits? May there come something *after* the digits that is part of the SKU?

Comment: @FunThomas: HGAF150 is the sku, and there is almost always a space between the sku (HGAF150) and the image extension name, except if it's the main image (it will only end with .jpg). But in the first example you see HGAF147, HGAF147 S.jpg

Comment: Maybe a screen caps of the desired result would be useful here. Also, will the directories always be `https://decormarket.com/SH/NL/`?

Comment: Yes directories will always be same. I updated the desired result now, please look, thanks!

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,"*" & MID(A1,30,7)& "*")`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad this produces good results for 1st 3 but for next batch (HGAF150) it starts at 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost sure that there is a formula that could get the SKU out of the string, but I find it easier to use a small VBA function that you can use as UDF. Also, there are other ways to implement it (eg using Regular Expressions) - that's a matter of taste.

```
Function getSKU(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim p As Long
    p = InStrRev(s, "/")
    If p > 0 Then s = Mid(s, p + 1)  ' Cut everything before the last slash
    
    p = InStrRev(s, ".")
    If p > 0 Then s = Left(s, p - 1)  ' Cut extension if any
    p = InStrRev(s, " ")
    If p > 0 Then s = Left(s, p - 1)  ' Cut prefix if any
    
    getSKU = s
End Function
```

Now you can use it with a formula like that (assuming your data starts in A2)

```
=IF(getSKU(A2)=getSKU(A1); B1+1;1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out from here. Excellent answer ^_^